# redis returns false everytime from promise return

Tags: javascript, redis

I am new to redis, at the moment using the redis client npm package to interact with it. I have a function which attempts to return a value from redis like so:

The key/val pair is like : `foo/true`

```
function getVal(key: string, field: string) {
    // updates value for that field
        return client.hget(key, field, function (hashGetError: any, result: any) {
            if (hashGetError) {
                // do something
            } else {
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    console.log("fetch result is: " + result); << here I can see a value i.e "true"
                    resolve(result);
                })
            }
    
        });
}
```

the calling code looks like this

```
let bar = getVal("key", "foo");
console.log(bar); << this is always returning false?
```

Any pointers are appreciated :)

Comment: `getVal` is just a wrapper on [`hget`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10584943/6243352) so it's not going to return anything different from `hget`. As you see, the callback from the asynchronous `hget` is needed to produce a result so you'll need to use a promise to chain from that; currently the promise isn't returned anywhere useful and not to the caller of `getVal` as you may think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: so this should work? let bar = await getVal("key", "foo"); or did i misunderstand?

Comment: No because the promise isn't returned to the caller scope. The promise should be on the outside of the `hget` and returned to the caller, then the promise fires the `hget` call which has the callback that `resolve`s the promise. Alternately, you could pass a callback into `getVal` and make that the callback to `hget`, but this doesn't seem any better than simply calling `hget` directly from the caller.

Comment: ahh! of course you are correct. That has fixed it for me. Actually it is wrapped as the client.hget call lives in a seperate module and i just reference the calling function via an import